# turning off one of my 2 monitors using python script

Tags: python, windows, winapi, monitor, win32gui

I have 2 monitors and when i watch movies on my main monitor, i want the other one to be off.
I don't want to push the power button because it is hard to find in the dark.

This code turn off both screens

```
class Mode(Object):
    STAND_BY = 1
    TURN_ON = -1
    TURN_OFF = 2

SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170 

win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, Mode.TURN_OFF)
```

I also tried to get a handle to my other screen that way:

```
monitors = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors(None, None)
(hSecondMon, _, (_, _, secondRight, secondButtom)) = monitors[1]
win32gui.SendMessage(hSecondMon, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, Mode.TURN_OFF)
```

but it didn't work.

However, I was able to change its color to black:

```
monitors = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors(None, None)
(_, _, (_, _, primRight, _)) = monitors[0]
(hSecondMon, _, (_, _, secondRight, secondButtom)) = monitors[1]

hDeskDC = win32gui.CreateDC(win32api.GetMonitorInfo(hSecondMon)['Device'], None, None)
brush = win32gui.GetSysColorBrush(win32con.COLOR_BACKGROUND)
win32gui.FillRect(hDeskDC, (0, 0, secondRight - primRight, secondButtom), brush)
```

but that is not good enough since as soon as my desktop background changes, it recolors the second screen.

Comment: isn't there PD programs that are able to do that? if so, you could try one to see if it has better success than python at this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what's a PD program?

Comment: There's a total absence of error checking. Why? How are you going to debug this without checking for errors?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wanted it to be readable for you. SendMessage returns 0 when it didn't work, 1 when it did work. All other functions behave as expected.

Comment: PD: public domain, like nircmd or other swiss army knife tools. If those tools work with your hardware, then you have a chance using python (or call them directly from python as a fast hack)

Comment: Well for now i just put a black image in full screen mode and that works :D